# Installing Django with pip, django-admin not found

Tags: python, django, macos, pip

I installed python using: `brew install python` and then eventually `pip install Django`. However when I try to run `django-admin.py startproject test` I just get a file not found. What did I forget?

Comment: django-admin is not on path, you could search for it `find / -name django-admin.py` and add it to your .profile/.bashrc/.whatever. Let me recommend using virtualenv for everything python related you do though. Installing it in a local environment prevents this kind of problem =)

Comment: Reposted it as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/3963953) to install django within a virtualenv and to create a project in a single step.

**Note:** You can use it for setting up your development environment. For production, check out [this post.](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/10/24/starting-a-django-14-project-the-right-way/)

Comment: That is a cool script. Am I able to put multiple django projects into the root folder of a virtualenv?

Comment: I don't think so. It's usually not considered a good practice to have multiple projects under a virtualenv as far as I know. You can have multiple apps within a project instead. That's the django way of doing things.

Comment: You could, but the point is to isolate each project's environment. Imagine that project Foo needs to upgrade to Django 1.5, while project Bar can't upgrade yet ... Having one virtualenv per project does the trick. The other advantage is that it's easy to deploy a virtualenv. One your dev machine do pip freeze, store the output in a file like requirements.txt, then on your server just make a new virtualenv and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. It will install all dependencies. Meanwhile, you can take a break B) In your case, it also solves the path problem.

Answer (score 5):

It is way better to use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.org), and install django in the virtualenv.

Comment: do I need to uninstall anything before getting started with virtualenv? and if so how should i go about clearing everything?

Comment: No, virtualenv will create an isolated environment -- ignoring everything you've installed "globally" thus far (if you use the `--no-site-packages` argument, but I think that's the default these days).

Comment: Solution: use `--system-site-packages`.

Comment: system-site-packages is now the default mode, isn't it?

Comment: --no-site-packages is the default. Just run virtualenv -h folks !

Answer (score 3):

`django-admin` is not on path, you could search for it `find / -name django-admin.py` and add it to your .profile/.bashrc/.whatever. Let me recommend using virtualenv for everything python related you do though. Installing it in a local environment prevents this kind of problem.

Each environment comes with its own Python distribution, so you can keep different versions of Python in different environments. It also ignores globally installed packages with the --no-site-packages flag (which is default) but this doesn't work properly with packages installed using eg Ubuntu's apt-get (they are in dist-packages iirc). Any packages installed using pip or easy_install inside the environment are also only local. This lets you simulate different deployments. But most importantly, it keeps the global environment clean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) version manager instead of virtualenv, you may need to run `asdf reshim python` in your shell to get pip-installed "executables" to show up on your path (so you can execute them by name).